# TLS v1 disable options in Corda

Tags: tls1.2, corda, activemq-artemis

Does anybody know if it is possible to disable TLS v1 in Corda ActiveMQ Artemis? I know Corda use TLS v1.2, but our problem is TLS v1 is enable in the system.

If I run `openssl s_client -connect IP:port -tls1` I get a sucessful response. Is there a way to disable TLS v1 in corda?

Answer (score 0):

TLS1 is not enabled. If you run `openssl s_client -connect IP:port -tls1` and try and connect to a node, you get a `wrong version number` error, indicating that TLS1 is not supported.

The list of supported TLS versions can be found here: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/ArtemisTcpTransport.kt. Only v1.2 is supported.